# Strange movement of objects when highlighted item in beamer is uncovered

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, highlighting

Can anyone explain to me why there is this strange "shift" of objects when passing from the first to the second slide in the below MWE?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    },
    beameralert/.style={alt=<#1>{fill=red!30,rounded corners,inner sep=1pt}{},anchor=base},
}

\newcommand*{\tikzarrow}[2]{%
  \tikz[
    baseline=(A.base),            
  ]\node[
    single arrow,                 
    single arrow head extend=2pt, 
    draw,                         
    inner sep=2pt,                
    top color=white,              
    bottom color=#1,              
    drop shadow                   
  ] (A) {#2};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Theorem}
Assume:
\begin{itemize}
  \item Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
\end{itemize}

\tikzarrow{yellow}{Then} \tikz[baseline=(A.base)] \node[beameralert=2] (A) {$a+b+c+d+e+f+g=47$.};
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

PS: The question is, in a sense, a follow-up of the accepted answer in [Highlighting in Beamer using TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84513/16865).

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18704/86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your code you perceive shifts between slides (*jumping effect*) because I suspect the style `beameralert` with the addition of `inner sep=1pt` if displayed just in the second slide changes the dimensions of the node. If I remove it, I get:

[image]

Indeed, the beauty of

```
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    }
}
```

that avoids jumping effects is that makes the elements of the TikZ picture (nodes, paths or whatever) *always* present, but only *visible* in some moments. One perceives jumping effects whenever in different slides elements appears magically only in some moments with their dimensions (at least this is what I've understood reading some questions/answers on the topic here).

Recalling my previous answer 
[Highlighting in Beamer using TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84513/highlighting-in-beamer-using-tikz-nodes#84608), it is also possible to use the following style:

```
\tikzset{
  background fill/.style={fill=#1},
  background fill/.default={block body.bg},
  fill on/.style={alt=#1{}{background fill}},
}
```

with the care of setting the default value equal to the background color of the block body. Then:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    }
}

\tikzset{
  background fill/.style={fill=#1},
  background fill/.default={block body.bg},
  fill on/.style={alt=#1{}{background fill}},
}

\newcommand*{\tikzarrow}[2]{%
  \tikz[
    baseline=(A.base),            
  ]\node[
    single arrow,                 
    single arrow head extend=2pt, 
    draw,                         
    inner sep=2pt,                
    top color=white,              
    bottom color=#1,              
    drop shadow                   
  ] (A) {#2};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Theorem}
Assume:
\begin{itemize}
  \item Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
\end{itemize}

\tikzarrow{yellow}{Then} \tikz[baseline=(A.base)] \node[rounded corners,background fill=red!30,fill on=<2>] (A) {$a+b+c+d+e+f+g=47$.};
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

will provide the same picture reported above.

Comment: OK, I understand your explanation of the problem. But I need `inner sep=1pt` ... Is there any chance of reparing my code so as to prevent the "jumping effect" (I mean without redefining everything)?

Comment: Yes, of course (maybe from my answer is not clear). The point is that you should be consistent with the dimensions: if you use `inner sep=1pt` in the `beameralert` then you should also use in the node `\node[beameralert=2,inner sep=1pt]`. That allows you to not perceive anymore the problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry, apparently I didn't really understand your answer :-) But now I do and it works fine! Thanks!