# Beamer: problematic use of \visible and \only in combination with TikZ to draw a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a problem with my graph and my background environment to highlight the edges in the "last" of my slides.

First I tried this:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Graphmodell Beispiel}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=white!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{selected vertex} = [vertex, fill=red!24]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\small]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]
\tikzstyle{ignored edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,black!20]

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw},level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm}
]
    %\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]
    \only<1,2>{\node[vertex] (1) {1}
        child {node[vertex] (2) {2}
            child{node[vertex] (3){3}}
            child{node[vertex] (4){4}}
        }
        child { node[vertex] (5) {5}
            child {node[vertex](6) {6}}
            child {node[vertex] (7){7}
                child{node[vertex] (8){8}}
                child{node[vertex] (9){9}}
            }
        }};
    \only<3>{\node[vertex, label=right:$T_{k}$] (1) {1}
        child {node[vertex, label=left:$T_{k-in}$] (2) {2}
            child{node[vertex] (3){3}}
            child{node[vertex] (4){4}}
        }
        child { node[vertex, label=right:$T_{k-out}$] (5) {5}
            child {node[vertex](6) {6}}
            child {node[vertex] (7){7}
                child{node[vertex] (8){8}}
                child{node[vertex] (9){9}}
            }
        }};

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \pause
        \foreach \source / \dest in {1/2,2/4,1/5,5/7,7/8}
            \path[selected edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\visible<3->{\begin{center}Fahrzeug $k \in k^{+}$ mit Start-Endpunktvektor $(4,8)$\end{center}}
\end{frame}
```

It worked just fine besides the fact that the graph was switching the positions slightly because of using `\only` instead of `\visible`.

But when I replace `\only` with `\visible` I don't know how to "background" my edges any more, because it gives me the error that the vertices aren't found.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Graphmodell Beispiel}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=white!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{selected vertex} = [vertex, fill=red!24]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\small]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]
\tikzstyle{ignored edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,black!20]

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw},level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm}
]
    %\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]
    \node{{\visible<1>{[vertex] (1) {1}
        child {node[vertex] (2) {2}
            child{node[vertex] (3){3}}
            child{node[vertex] (4){4}}
        }
        child { node[vertex] (5) {5}
            child {node[vertex](6) {6}}
            child {node[vertex] (7){7}
                child{node[vertex] (8){8}}
                child{node[vertex] (9){9}}
        }
        }}}};
    \only<3>{\node[vertex, label=right:$T_{k}$] (1) {1}
        child {node[vertex, label=left:$T_{k-in}$] (2) {2}
            child{node[vertex] (3){3}}
            child{node[vertex] (4){4}}
        }
        child { node[vertex, label=right:$T_{k-out}$] (5) {5}
            child {node[vertex](6) {6}}
            child {node[vertex] (7){7}
                child{node[vertex] (8){8}}
                child{node[vertex] (9){9}}
            }
        }};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \pause
        \foreach \source / \dest in {1/2,2/4,1/5,5/7,7/8}
            \path[selected edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\visible<3->{\begin{center}Fahrzeug $k \in k^{+}$ mit Start-Endpunktvektor $(4,8)$\end{center}}
\end{frame}
```

Does anybody know how to get out of this trouble?

P.S: Thanks Claudio for the format. I understood that you just have to indent inside the code

Comment: It's almost the same problem of [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55806/13304): Daniel's solution is the recommended one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in the comment, the Daniel's approach from [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/mindmap-tikzpicture-in-beamer-reveal-step-by-step) allows to avoid the so called *jumping effect* (the movement of the graph you perceive); this is a well known problem and on the site there are several references; some of them are:

- [Avoiding jumping frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer)
- [How can I fix jumping TikZ pictures in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18704/how-can-i-fix-jumping-tikz-pictures-in-beamer)
- [Strange movement of objects when highlighted item in beamer is uncovered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85205/strange-movement-of-objects-when-highlighted-item-in-beamer-is-uncovered)

Notice that, in your example, you just have to apply the style `visible on` to the nodes (and labels) that have to appear later on, not to all `child` nodes (that's something required if you want to make the whole vertex appear later on).

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

  \tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Graphmodell Beispiel}

\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,fill=white!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt}}
\tikzset{selected vertex/.style={vertex, fill=red!24}}
\tikzset{edge/.style={draw,thick,-}}
\tikzset{weight/.style={font=\small}}
\tikzset{selected edge/.style={draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50}}
\tikzset{ignored edge/.style={draw,line width=5pt,-,black!20}}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw},level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm}
]
    \node[vertex] (1) {1}
        child {node[vertex] (2) {2}
            child{node[vertex] (3){3}}
            child{node[vertex] (4){4}}
        }
        child { node[vertex] (5) {5}
            child {node[vertex](6) {6}}
            child {node[vertex] (7){7}
                child{node[vertex] (8){8}}
                child{node[vertex] (9){9}}
            }
        };
    \node[vertex,visible on=<3>, label={[visible on=<3>]right:$T_{k}$}] (1) {1}
        child {node[vertex, visible on=<3>, label={[visible on=<3>]left:$T_{k-in}$}] (2) {2}
            child{node[vertex] (3){3}}
            child{node[vertex] (4){4}}
        }
        child { node[vertex, visible on=<3>,label={[visible on=<3>]right:$T_{k-out}$}] (5) {5}
            child {node[vertex](6) {6}}
            child {node[vertex] (7){7}
                child{node[vertex] (8){8}}
                child{node[vertex] (9){9}}
            }
        };

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \pause
        \foreach \source / \dest in {1/2,2/4,1/5,5/7,7/8}
            \path[selected edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\visible<3->{\begin{center}Fahrzeug $k \in k^{+}$ mit Start-Endpunktvektor $(4,8)$\end{center}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

All the styles defined via `\tikzstyle` in your example have been changed into `\tikzset` as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).