# Figure in beamer moves around

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

This is a `MWE` of my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[c]

\column{.7\textwidth}
\only<1>{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{fig.png}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\only<2>{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{fig.png}};
    \draw[green,thick,rounded corners] (4.8,5.2) ellipse (0.28 and 1.5);
    \draw[->, line width=2pt, -triangle 60] (6.3,5.2) -- (5.2,5.2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\only<3>{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{fig.png}};
    \draw[green,thick,rounded corners] (5.8,3) ellipse (0.28 and 1.5);
    \draw[->, line width=2pt, -triangle 60] (7.1,3) -- (6.1,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\column{.35\textwidth}
\vspace{-1.cm}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=gray,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black,bg=}
\usebeamercolor{normal text}
\begin{itemize}
\item \alert<+>{Some text goes here sdsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf.}\\[4ex]
\item \alert<+>{Some more text here sdfdsf.}\\[4ex]
\item \alert<+>{And some text here.}
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This creates three slides with the same image:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It might not be noticeable when seen separate but the grey square does not maintain a fixed position within the slides. How do I get it to stop moving around?

Here's the grey square I use: [image]

Comment: You might have a look to the answer of [Beamer: problematic use of \visible and \only in combination with TikZ to draw a graph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99119/13304): it contains references to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Claudio, I followed that answer and wrapped the code around an `overlayarea` environment and it worked. Want to make that into an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Well someone already provided an answer that also works.

Comment: Perhaps also worth looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18704/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey: a pointer to that question is also present in the link I added :) I think for the OP all the references given there are of help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Claudio, you should use `\visible` instead of `\only` if you don't want things to move around from one slide to the next:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[c]

\column{.7\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{fig.png}};
    \visible<2>{
        \draw[green,thick,rounded corners] (4.8,5.2) ellipse (0.28 and 1.5);
        \draw[->, line width=2pt, -triangle 60] (6.3,5.2) -- (5.2,5.2);
    }
    \visible<3>{
        \draw[green,thick,rounded corners] (5.8,3) ellipse (0.28 and 1.5);
        \draw[->, line width=2pt, -triangle 60] (7.1,3) -- (6.1,3);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}


\column{.35\textwidth}
\vspace{-1.cm}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=gray,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black,bg=}
\usebeamercolor{normal text}
\begin{itemize}
\item \alert<+>{Some text goes here sdsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf.}\\[4ex]
\item \alert<+>{Some more text here sdfdsf.}\\[4ex]
\item \alert<+>{And some text here.}
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```