# Beamer overlay box around text - the correct way?

Tags: beamer, boxes, highlighting, overlays

I have something that "works," but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution. I want to box some text after an itemize in beamer, so this is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Software-as-a-Service?
  \item Platform-as-a-Service?
  \item \only<-4>{Infrastructure-as-a-Service}\only<5->{\fcolorbox{red}{white}{Infrastructure-as-a-Service}}?
  \item Other-stuff-as-a-Service?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get the effect that I want (with some added space on the boxed slide, which is not ideal), but I'm wondering if there's a more natural way to do this? I tried searching online and the trusty `texdoc beamer`, but maybe I'm looking in all the wrong places.

I also tried:

```
\item \fcolorbox<beamer:6>{red}{white}{Infrastructure-as-a-Service}?
```

but that left me with a black box until the red one was highlighted

Comment: It's not clear to me why are you using `\only<-2>{Infrastructure-as-a-Service}`. All you want is to have a boxed item to appear on frames 3 onwards?

Comment: Perhaps the behaviour desired is the one addressed in [Highlighting in beamer using TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84513/13304)?

Comment: Yes, the effect is the same as in the other post. I was looking to have something boxed afterwards, I noticed that there's a typo in my original so I've edited the MWE accordingly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the tried and tested `tikzmark` idea

[image: animation]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% tikzmark command, for shading over items
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Software-as-a-Service?
  \item Platform-as-a-Service?
  \item \tikzmark{infrastructure}{Infrastructure-as-a-Service}
  \item Other-stuff-as-a-Service?
\end{itemize}

    \pause\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[draw=red,thick,double,fill opacity=0.2] ($(infrastructure)+(-0.5,0.4)$) rectangle ($(infrastructure)+(6,-0.2)$);}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Got it, that's exactly the functionality I was looking for! Any idea why it pauses twice on the last item in the list? I tried stopping it from doing that by moving around the `\pause`, but I haven't been successful.

Comment: @zestrada remove the `\pause` command and use     `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw<+->[draw=red,thick,double,fill opacity=0.2] ($(infrastructure)+(-0.5,0.4)$) rectangle ($(infrastructure)+(6,-0.2)$);}` instead.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Didn't even think to try `<+->`!

Answer (score 11):

A different approach could be to exploit the styles defined in [Highlighting in Beamer using TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84513/highlighting-in-beamer-using-tikz-nodes#84608).

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}    

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    },
}

\tikzset{
  background fill/.style={fill=#1},
  background fill/.default={white},
  fill on/.style={alt=#1{}{background fill}},
}

\tikzset{
  background draw/.style={draw=#1},
  background draw/.default={white},
  draw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background draw}},
}

\tikzset{
  background filldraw/.style args={#1 filled by #2}{draw=#1, fill=#2},
  background filldraw/.default=white filled by white,
  filldraw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background filldraw}},
}

\tikzset{highlighting/.style={
   append after command={
   \pgfextra{
      \path[rounded corners,
         background draw=red,
         draw on=<#1>,
         overlay] ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(-0.015,-0.1)$) % to have some offset
         rectangle ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(0.015,0.065)$);
      }   
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\highlight}{r<> m}{%
\tikz[baseline=(A.base)] 
 \node[highlighting=#1,
   inner sep=0pt] (A) {#2};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Itemize with styles}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Software-as-a-Service?
  \item Platform-as-a-Service?
  \item \highlight<5>{Infrastructure-as-a-Service}?
  \item Other-stuff-as-a-Service?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

> **Notes on the code**

The TikZ node created does not occupy to much space due to the option `inner sep=0pt`, but since its dimensions are very tight around the text, the highlighting box created adds some space around (via offsets created thanks to the `calc` library). In order to avoid that this extra space may corrupts the alignment, the `overlay` option has been introduced to the highlighting path.

Now, without changing anything inside the `document`, it is possible to obtain different effects by selecting the different styles:

```
\tikzset{highlighting/.style={
   append after command={
   \pgfextra{
      \path[rounded corners,
         background fill=red!30, % filling
         fill on=<#1>, % filling overlay specification
         overlay] ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(-0.015,-0.1)$) % to have some offset
         rectangle ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(0.015,0.065)$);
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

gives:

[image]

while:

```
\tikzset{highlighting/.style={
   append after command={
   \pgfextra{
      \path[rounded corners,
         background filldraw=red filled by red!30, % border+filling
         filldraw on=<#1>, % overlay specification
         overlay] ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(-0.015,-0.1)$) % to have some offset
         rectangle ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(0.015,0.065)$);
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

gives:

[image]

> **Customizable offsets**

With this improved version it is possible to customize the highlighted area (an idea borrowed from the `hf-tikz` package) via offsets. This offsets ultimately are pgfkeys whose values have to be declared within the optional argument of the `\highlight` command:

```
\highlight<overlay specification>[offsets]{text}
```

If no `[offsets]` are specified, the initial values are taken.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    },
}

\tikzset{
  background fill/.style={fill=#1},
  background fill/.default={white},
  fill on/.style={alt=#1{}{background fill}},
}

\tikzset{
  background draw/.style={draw=#1},
  background draw/.default={white},
  draw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background draw}},
}

\tikzset{
  background filldraw/.style args={#1 filled by #2}{draw=#1, fill=#2},
  background filldraw/.default=white filled by white,
  filldraw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background filldraw}},
}

\pgfkeys{/highlight/.cd,
  above right offset/.initial={0.015,0.065},
  above right offset/.get=\aboverightoffset,
  above right offset/.store in=\aboverightoffset,
  below left offset/.initial={-0.015,-0.1},
  below left offset/.get=\belowleftoffset,
  below left offset/.store in=\belowleftoffset,
}

\tikzset{highlighting/.style={
   append after command={
   \pgfextra{
      \path[rounded corners,
         background filldraw=red filled by red!30,% border+filling
         filldraw on=<#1>, % overlay specification
         overlay] ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(\belowleftoffset)$) % to have some offset
         rectangle ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(\aboverightoffset)$);
      }   
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\highlight}{r<> O{} m}{%
\pgfkeys{/highlight/.cd,#2}
\tikz[baseline=(A.base)] 
 \node[highlighting=#1,
   inner sep=0pt] (A) {#3};%  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Itemize with styles}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Software-as-a-Service?
  \item Platform-as-a-Service?
  \item \highlight<5>{Infrastructure-as-a-Service}?  
  \item \highlight<6>[below left offset={-0.1,-0.2},above right offset={0.25,0.15}]{Other-stuff-as-a-Service}?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Congratulations for having become a trusted user (rep > 20000)!

Comment: This solution allows for a box overlay of more than 1 bullet point, which is great.

Comment: @PanchoPino: yes, you're right. According to the offsets provided, you have a degree of freedom that allows to overlay as much bullets you want.

Comment: Is there a better way if I want all the items appear like that?

Comment: Always my best regards :-)