# Tikz: how to make a node within a text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, spacing

I would like to add a tikz node within a text in such a way that it doesn't add space between the lines. In particular, I'd like to animate (in beamer) a frame around the text without it taking space.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Many thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
     alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
       \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
     },
    BeamerAlert/.style={alt=#1{draw=red,thick,rounded corners}{},anchor=base}
}

\newcommand<>{\tikzMe}[1]{
   \tikz[baseline]\node[BeamerAlert=#2] {${#1}$};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  This is an \tikzMe<2>{\mathsf{example}} of
  text with the space between lines changed because of the tikz
  node. Here is another line whose spacing is natural.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is the same already asked in [Reduce white space around TikZ picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95649/13304). Try to add an `inner sep` and see what happens.

Comment: If the problem is solved, do you mind if we close this question as duplicate of the one I linked?

Comment: I'd love to, but I don't see how...

Comment: Don't mind about this: I will propose to close it and sooner the reviewers will close it :)

Comment: Actually, it isn't really solving my problem, since the box is still messing my layout. I mean, I want the box to somehow overlay over the surrounding space, and this seems to not be doable with a negative outer sep.

Comment: I think you borrowed `\tikzMe` from Qrrbrbirlbel's answer in: [Highlighting in beamer using TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84513/highlighting-in-beamer-using-tikz-nodes). That's fine, but you can not fine tune the portion of the highlighted area. Indeed, with the styles I defined in the other answer, that's possible; a practical implementation is: [Beamer overlay box around text - the correct way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107209/13304). See in the animation how the highlighted space around of the text changes.