# Make blue box appear after pause command in beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

I am trying to the following in a beamer presentation.

```
Slide 1: This is
Slide 2: This is a test
Slide 3: This is BLUEBOXa testBLUEBOX
```

(BLUEBOXa testBLUEBOX should be written "a test" with a blue box around it.)

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  This is
  \pause
  a test\\
  \pause
  {This is\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1)
    {a test};}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

First two slides are okay, but I don't know how to make the third slide turn blue after a pause command. Does it make sense to use PGF/TikZ here? Is there an easier way?

Comment: I think you can have a look to [Beamer with Tikz graphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183956/13304) and related Q/A for more insights.

Comment: Or perhaps the Q/A here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107042/32374

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the following approach work for you?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\tcbset{colframe=white,colback=white,nobeforeafter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This is \pause
        \only<3>{\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{5,61,245}}
        \tcbox[colback=white,colframe=mycolor,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base]{a test}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]