# Rounded corner box in itemized environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, itemize, baseline

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rbox}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[rounded corners=3pt, draw]{#1};                                                                                             
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item \rbox{Hello World in rounded corner box} Hello World
    \item Hello
    \item World
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I was expecting 'Hello World in rounded corner box' perfectly aligned with the corresponding bullet point. In reality, 'Hello World in ronded corner box' is placed such that the bullet appears in it. Moreover, the baseline alignment is not correct.

What do I need to do to get this right?

Comment: You may want to have a look to: [Beamer overlay box around text - the correct way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107209/13304). The concept is explained considering overlays, but it is simple to port it in article mode.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino perfect! [baseline] was the solution. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using baseline option in tikz was the solution.

Here is the MWE that produces the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rbox}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \node[rounded corners=3pt, draw, anchor=base]{#1};                                                                                
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item \rbox{HelloWorld} Hello World
    \item Hello
    \item World
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```