# highlight the desired item

Tags: beamer, graphics, highlighting

How can I mark any desired item/statement in red circle/ oval mark as shown in this slide. Can it be animated too?

[image]

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84513/highlighting-in-beamer-using-tikz-nodes?rq=1

Comment: appears to be to complicated for a small job (overkill?). Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple possibility is to use the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
mytext/.style={
  top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,colback=gray!10,colframe=structure}
}
\newcommand<>\HLtext[2][]{%
  \hspace*{-4pt}\tcbhighmath[mytext,#1]{\text{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Consensus to define FD symptoms}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Epigastric discomfort or pain.
\item \HLtext{Postprandial heaviness.}
\item Early satiety.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\HLtext` is overlay aware.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say 'overlay aware'? (Sorry if I'm not up-to-date on my `beamer` lingo.)

Comment: @SeanAllred that it admits overlay specifications, as in `\Hltext<3->{text}`.