# Separate diferents subcircuits from a circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, siunitx, circuitikz, electronics

I made this circuit, but I would like to separate the circuit into different subcircuits like the one shown in the image. I would like that by commenting on a subcircuit I can reproduce the other subcircuits, that is, show different parts of the circuit as requested.

[image]

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]\draw

    %Inicio de la etapa de potencia
    (15,0) node[npn](Q5){$Q5$}
    (Q5.B) --++ (-1,0) coordinate (B)

    to[R,l_=$R_{17}$,*-*]++(0,3.54) coordinate (B1)% node[vcc](VCC){$+10\volt$}%Activar y desactivar para solo esta etapa
    -| (Q5.C)

    (B) to[C,l=$C_{7}$] ++ (-2,0) coordinate (F)%Desactivar para unir con las demás etapas.

    (B) --++(0,-1.5) coordinate (C) --++(1,0) --++ (0,-0.5) node[npn,anchor=C](Q4){$Q_{4}$}
    (C) --++(-1,0) --++(0,-0.71) node[potentiometershape, rotate=-90,anchor=west,label=south west:$R_{V1}$, font=\large](P){}
    (P.wiper) -| (Q4.B)
    (P.east) --++(0,-0.71) --++ (1,0) coordinate (D)
    (D) -| (Q4.E)

    (Q5.E) to[R, l = $R_{13}$,*-*]++ (0,-2) coordinate (A)
    to[C,l=$C_{5}$] ++ (2,0) to [R,l=$R_{L}$,*-*] ++(0,-2) node[vee](VEE){$-10\volt$}
    (A) to[R,l=$R_{14}$,*-*] ++(0,-2) node[pnp,anchor=E](Q6){$Q_{6}$} ++(0,-2)
    (Q6.B) --++(-1,0) coordinate (E)

    to[R,l=$R_{12}$,*-*] ++(0,-2) coordinate (G)% node[vee](VEE){$-10\volt$}%Activar y desactivar para solo esta etapa
    %
    -| (Q6.C)
    (D) -| (E)
    %Fin de la etapa de potencia


    %Inicio de la etapa de Incursora
    (F) to[R,l=$R_{16}$,*-*]++ (0,-7.54) coordinate (F1) -| (G)
    (F) to[C,l=$C_{4}$,*-*]++(-2,0) coordinate (F2) to[R,l=$R_{10}$,*-*] ++(0,-7.54) coordinate (F3) -| (F1)
    (F) node[pnp,anchor=C](Q3){$Q_{3}$} ++(0,2)
    (Q3.E) to[R,l=$R_{11}$,*-*] ++(0,2) coordinate (F4) -| (B1)
    (Q3.E) --++(1,0) to[C,l_=$C_{6}$,*-*]++(0,2) -| (B1)
    (Q3.B) -| (F2)
    (Q3.B) ++ (-1.16,0) coordinate (G1) to[R,l=$R_{15}$,*-*]++(0,2.77) coordinate (F5) -| (F4)

    (G1) to[C,l=$C_{2}$,*-*]++(-2,0) coordinate (G2)%Desactivar para unir con las demás etapas.

    %(F3) ++(1,0) node[vee](VEE){$-10\volt$}%Activar y desactivar para solo esta etapa
    %(F4) node[vcc](VCC){$+10\volt$}%Activar y desactivar para solo esta etapa
    %Fin de la etapa de Incursora


    %Inicio de la Etapa Diferencial
    (G2) to[R,l=$R_{8}$,*-*]++(0,2.77)  coordinate (H1) -| (F5)
    (G2) --++(0,-0.9) coordinate (H2) to[R,l=$R_{9}$,-*] ++(0,-7.41) coordinate(H3) -| (F3)
    (H2)--++(0,-0.6) coordinate (H4) --++(1,0) to[C,l=$C_{3}$] ++(0,-2) node[vee](VEE){$-10\volt$}
    (H4)--++(-0.5,0) node[npn,anchor=B,xscale=-1, label=left:$Q_{2}$](Q2) {}
    (Q2.E) --++ (0,-0.1) coordinate (I1) to[R,l=$R_{7}$] ++(0,-5.94) coordinate (H5) -| (H3)
    (Q2.C) to[R,l=$R_{6}$] ++(0,3.5) coordinate (H6) -| (H1)
    (I1) ++ (0,-1)to[R,l=$R_{5}$]++(-2,0) coordinate(I2) to[R,l=$R_4$] ++ (0,-4.94) coordinate (J1) -| (H5)
    (I2) --++ (0,1.1) node[npn,anchor=E](Q1){$Q_{1}$}
    (Q1.C) to[R,l=$R_{3}$] ++(0,3.5) coordinate(J2) -| (H6)
    (Q1.B) to[C,l=$C_{1}$] ++(-2,0) to[short,label=$V_{in}$,-o] ++(-0.5,0)
    (Q1.B)  ++ (-0.5,0) to[R,l=$R_{2}$] ++(0,-6.81) -| (J1)
    (Q1.B) ++ (-0.5,0) to[R,l=$R_{1}$] ++ (0,4.27) -| (J2)

    %(J1) ++(1,0) node[vee](VEE){$-10\volt$}%Activar y desactivar para solo esta etapa
    %(J2) ++(1,0) node[vcc](VCC){$+10\volt$}%Activar y desactivar para solo esta etapa
    %Fin de la Etapa Diferencial
;\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! I have some idea, but could you please post a complete but *minimal* example, not the fully fledged circuit? And could you specify in which way you want to separate them... As independent figures, as slides in beamer, whatever?

Comment: Is separate the 3 stages (differential stage, power stage and other stage), in 3 subcircuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\newcommand{\volt}{\si{\volt}}
\newcommand{\amp}{\si{\amp}}
\newcommand{\ohm}{\si{\ohm}}
\newcommand{\watt}{\si{\watt}}

\ctikzset{%
monopoles/vcc/arrow={Triangle[width=0.8*\scaledwidth, length=\scaledwidth]},
monopoles/vee/arrow={Triangle[width=6pt, length=8pt]},
resistors/thickness=3,
}


\begin{document}
\ctikzsubcircuitdef{power}{in 1,in 3,in 2}{
    coordinate (#1-in 1) to[R,l=$R_{17}$,*-*] ++(0,-4.50) coordinate (#1-in 3)
    (#1-in 3) --++(1.5,0) node[npn,anchor=B](Q5){$Q_{5}$}
    (#1-in 1) -| (Q5.C)
    (Q5.E) to[R,l=$R_{13}$,*-*] ++(0,-2) coordinate (A) to[C,l_=$C_{5}$] ++(2,0) to[R,l=$R_{L}$,*-*] ++(0,-2) node[vee](VEE){$-10\volt$}
    (A) to[R,l=$R_{14}$,*-*] ++(0,-2) node[pnp, anchor=E](Q6){$Q_{6}$}
    (#1-in 3) --++(0,-1.5) coordinate(A1) --++(1,0) --++ (0,-0.5) node[npn,anchor=C](Q4){$Q_{4}$}
    (Q4.E) --++(0,-0.5) --++(-1,0) coordinate(A2)
    (A1) --++(-1,0) --++(0,-0.71) node[potentiometershape, rotate=-90,anchor=west,label=south west:$R_{V1}$, font=\large](P){}
    (P.wiper) -| (Q4.B)
    (P.east) --++(0,-0.71) -| (A2)
    (A2) --++(0,-1.5) coordinate (A3) -| (Q6.B)
    (A3) to[R,l=$R_{12}$,*-] ++(0,-2) coordinate (#1-in 2)
    (Q6.C) --++(0,-1.5) -| (#1-in 2)
}

\ctikzsubcircuitdef{incursora}{in 1, in 2, in 3, out 1, out 2, out 3}{
coordinate (#1-in 3) --++(0.5,0) node[pnp, anchor=B](Q3){$Q_{3}$}
(#1-in 3) to[R,l=$R_{15}$,*-*] ++(0,3.23) coordinate (#1-in 1)
(#1-in 3) --++(0,-1.27) coordinate (B1) to[R,l=$R_{10}$,*-*] ++(0,-7.81) coordinate (#1-in 2)
(Q3.E) to[R,l=$R_{11}$,*-*] ++(0,2.46) coordinate (B3)
(Q3.E) --++(1.5,0) to[C,l=$C_{6}$,*-*] ++(0,2.46) coordinate (#1-out 1) --(B3) -| (#1-in 1)
(Q3.C) --++(0,-0.5) coordinate (#1-out 3) to[R,l=$R_{16}$,*-*] ++(0,-7.81) coordinate (#1-out 2) -| (#1-in 2)
(B1) --++(0.4,0) to[C,l=$C_{4}$] ++(0.5,0) -| (#1-out 3)
}

\ctikzsubcircuitdef{diferential}{in 1,out 1, out 2,out 3}{
    coordinate (#1-in 1) --++(1,0) node[npn, anchor=B](Q1){$Q_{1}$}
    (Q1.C) --++(0,1) coordinate (#1-out 3) to[R,l=$R_{3}$,*-] ++(0,2) coordinate (C)
    (Q1.E) to[R,l=$R_{4}$,*-] ++(0,-6) coordinate (C2)
    (#1-in 1) to[R,l=$R_{1}$,*-*] ++(0,5) -| (C)
    (#1-in 1) to[R,l=$R_{2}$,*-*] ++(0,-7.31) -| (C2)
    (Q1.E) to[R,l_=$R_{5}$,*-*] ++(2.5,0) coordinate (C3) to[R,l=$R_{7}$,*-*] ++(0,-6.54) coordinate (C6) -| (C2)
    (C3) node[npn,xscale=-1, anchor=E,label=left:$Q_{2}$](Q2){} ++(0,1.5)
    (Q2.C) to[R,l=$R_{6}$,*-*] ++(0,4.23) coordinate (C4) -| (C)
    (Q2.B) --++(0.5,0) coordinate (C5) to[R,l=$R_{9}$,*-*] ++(0,-7.31) coordinate (#1-out 2) -| (C6)
    (C5) to[R,l=$R_{8}$,*-*] ++(0,5) coordinate (#1-out 1) -| (C4)
    (C5) --++(1,0) to[C,l=$C_{3}$,*-*] ++(0,-2) node[vee](VEE){$-10\volt$}
}
\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{power}
\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{incursora}
\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{diferential}

\begin{circuitikz}\draw
    (0,0)\incursora{incur}{out 3} to[C,l=$C_{7}$,*-*]++(3,0) \power{power}{in 3}
    (incur-out 1) -| (power-in 1)
    (incur-out 2) -| (power-in 2)
    (incur-in 3) to[C,l=$C_{2}$,*-*]++(-6,0) \diferential{dif}{out 3}
    (incur-in 1) -| (dif-out 1)
    (incur-in 2) -| (dif-out 2)
    (dif-in 1) to[C,l=$C_{1}$,*-*] ++(-2,0) to[short,-o, label=$V_{in}$] ++(-0.5,0)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is nice --- but still you need a strategy to "switch on" each one independently.

Comment: Yes, but I don't use "switch on". How work it??

Comment: Sorry, I fear we misunderstood each other. I mean that what I tried to do was a way to plot, using the same circuit code, one stage at time...

Answer (score 2):

I will give you an idea on how I would do it if I need independent figures (like the ones for a book, say) and then a global one.

The trick is to have the main coordinates (starting, rails, etc) defined at the start of the circuit. Then you can draw each one of the stages independently, like in this example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    % first part. Start at (origin1), rails at VCC, VEE
    \coordinate (origin 1) at (0,0);
    \path (origin 1) ++ (0,4) coordinate(rail +);
    \path (origin 1) ++ (0,-4) coordinate(rail -);
    % drawing the sub circuit 1
    \iffalse
        \draw (origin 1) node[above]{$v_i$} to[short, o-*] ++(0.5,0)
        node[npn, anchor=B](Q1){Q1}
        (Q1.B) to[R] (Q1.B |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
        (Q1.B) to[R] (Q1.B |- rail -) node[vee]{}
        (Q1.C) to[R] (Q1.C |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
        (Q1.E) to[R] (Q1.E |- rail -) node[vee]{}
        (Q1.C) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(out 1);
        \coordinate (origin 2) at (out 1);
    \else
         \coordinate (origin 2) at (0,0);
    \fi
    % ok, now we have first subcircuit drawn.
    % Let's go with the second.
    % drawing the sub circuit 2
    \iftrue
        \draw (origin 2) node[above]{$v_{i_2}$} to[short, o-*] ++(0.5,0)
        node[npn, anchor=B](Q2){Q2}
        (Q2.B) to[R] (Q2.B |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
        (Q2.B) to[R] (Q2.B |- rail -) node[vee]{}
        (Q2.C) to[R] (Q2.C |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
        (Q2.E) to[R] (Q2.E |- rail -) node[vee]{}
        (Q2.C) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(out 2);
    \fi
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this like it is, you have:

[image]

And with the second (or the first) `\iftrue` transformed to `\iffalse`, you have:

[image]
[image]

Notice that the two stage are not *graphically* identical to the joined ones, but they are *electrically* the same.

Another option is to play with colors (you can wrap the first part of the circuit in `scope` groups and change for each figure).

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
        % first part. Start at (origin1), rails at VCC, VEE
        \coordinate (origin 1) at (0,0);
        \path (origin 1) ++ (0,4) coordinate(rail +);
        \path (origin 1) ++ (0,-4) coordinate(rail -);
        % drawing the sub circuit 1
        \begin{scope}[color=gray!50]
            \draw (origin 1) node[above]{$v_i$} to[short, o-*] ++(0.5,0)
            node[npn, anchor=B](Q1){Q1}
            (Q1.B) to[R] (Q1.B |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
            (Q1.B) to[R] (Q1.B |- rail -) node[vee]{}
            (Q1.C) to[R] (Q1.C |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
            (Q1.E) to[R] (Q1.E |- rail -) node[vee]{}
            (Q1.C) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(out 1);
            \coordinate (origin 2) at (out 1);
        \end{scope}
        % ok, now we have first subcircuit drawn.
        % Let's go with the second.
        % drawing the sub circuit 2
        \begin{scope}[
            % color=gray!50 % uncomment to gray out the second stage
            ]
            \draw (origin 2) node[above]{$v_{i_2}$} to[short, o-*] ++(0.5,0)
            node[npn, anchor=B](Q2){Q2}
            (Q2.B) to[R] (Q2.B |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
            (Q2.B) to[R] (Q2.B |- rail -) node[vee]{}
            (Q2.C) to[R] (Q2.C |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
            (Q2.E) to[R] (Q2.E |- rail -) node[vee]{}
            (Q2.C) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(out 2);
        \end{scope}
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, this solution (more or less) works perfectly with beamer:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\tikzset{% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84513/38080
    invisible/.style={color=gray!50},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
  }\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape]
        % first part. Start at (origin1), rails at VCC, VEE
        \coordinate (origin 1) at (0,0);
        \path (origin 1) ++ (0,4) coordinate(rail +);
        \path (origin 1) ++ (0,-4) coordinate(rail -);
        % drawing the sub circuit 1
        \begin{scope}[visible on=<{2,4-}>]
                \draw (origin 1) node[above]{$v_i$} to[short, o-*] ++(0.5,0)
                node[npn, anchor=B](Q1){Q1}
                (Q1.B) to[R] (Q1.B |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
                (Q1.B) to[R] (Q1.B |- rail -) node[vee]{}
                (Q1.C) to[R] (Q1.C |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
                (Q1.E) to[R] (Q1.E |- rail -) node[vee]{}
                (Q1.C) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(out 1);
                \coordinate (origin 2) at (out 1);
            \end{scope}
        % ok, now we have first subcircuit drawn.
        % Let's go with the second.
        % drawing the sub circuit 2
            \begin{scope}[visible on=<3->]
                \draw (origin 2) node[above]{$v_{i_2}$} to[short, o-*] ++(0.5,0)
                node[npn, anchor=B](Q2){Q2}
                (Q2.B) to[R] (Q2.B |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
                (Q2.B) to[R] (Q2.B |- rail -) node[vee]{}
                (Q2.C) to[R] (Q2.C |- rail +) node[vcc]{}
                (Q2.E) to[R] (Q2.E |- rail -) node[vee]{}
                (Q2.C) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(out 2);
            \end{scope}
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]